# PWA: Chrome warning "Service worker does not have the 'fetch' handler"

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

I'm currently unsuccessfully trying to make my PWA installable. I have registered a SertviceWorker and linked a manifest as well as I am listening on the beforeInstallPromt event.

My ServiceWorker is listening to any `fetch` event.

My problem is, that the created beforeInstall banner is just being shown on Chrome desktop but on mobile I get a warning in Chrome inspection tab "Application" in the "Manifest" section:

```
Installability
Service worker does not have the 'fetch' handler
```

You can check the message on https://dev.testapp.ga/

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
// Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
deferredPrompt = e;
mtShowInstallButton();
});
```

manifest.json

```
{"name":"TestApp","short_name":"TestApp","start_url":"https://testapp.ga/loginCheck","icons":[{"src":"https://testapp.ga/assets/icons/launcher-ldpi.png","sizes":"36x36","density":0.75},{"src":"https://testapp.ga/assets/icons/launcher-mdpi.png","sizes":"48x48","density":1},{"src":"https://testapp.ga/assets/icons/launcher-hdpi.png","sizes":"72x72","density":1.5},{"src":"https://testapp.ga/assets/icons/launcher-xhdpi.png","sizes":"96x96","density":2},{"src":"https://testapp.ga/assets/icons/launcher-xxhdpi.png","sizes":"144x144","density":3},{"src":"https://testapp.ga/assets/icons/launcher-xxxhdpi.png","sizes":"192x192","density":4},{"src":"https://testapp.ga/assets/icons/launcher-web.png","sizes":"512x512","density":10}],"display":"standalone","background_color":"#ffffff","theme_color":"#0288d1","orientation":"any"}
```

ServiceWorker:

```
//This array should NEVER contain any file which doesn't exist. Otherwise no single file can be cached.
var preCache=[
  '/favicon.png',
  '/favicon.ico',
  '/assets/Bears/bear-standard.png',
  '/assets/jsInclude/mathjax.js',
  '/material.js',
  '/main.js',
  'functions.js',
  '/material.css',
  '/materialcolors.css',
  '/user.css',
  '/translations.json',
  '/roboto.css',
  '/sw.js',
  '/'
];
//Please specify the version off your App. For every new version, any files are being refreched.
var appVersion="v0.2.1";
//Please specify all files which sould never be cached
var noCache=[
  '/api/'
];

//On installation of app, all files from preCache are being stored automatically.
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
      caches.open(appVersion+'-offline').then(function(cache) {
          return cache.addAll(preCache).then(function(){
            console.log('mtSW: Given files were successfully pre-cached')
          });
      })
  );
});

function shouldCache(url) {
    //Checking if url is market as noCache
    var isNoCache=noCache.includes(url.substr(8).substr(url.substr(8).indexOf("/")))||noCache.includes((url.substr(8).substr(url.substr(8).indexOf("/"))).substr(0,(url.substr(8).substr(url.substr(8).indexOf("/"))).indexOf("?")));
    //Checking of hostname of request != current hostname
    var isOtherHost=url.substr(8).substr(0,url.substr(8).indexOf("/"))!=location.hostname&&url.substr(7).substr(0,url.substr(7).indexOf("/"))!=location.hostname;
    return((url.substr(0,4)=="http"||url.substr(0,3)=="ftp") && isNoCache==false && isOtherHost==false);
}
//If any fetch fails, it will look for the request in the cache and serve it from there first
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  //Trying to answer with "online" version if fails, using cache.
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
      if(shouldCache(response.url)) {
        console.log('mtSW: Adding file to cache: '+response.url);
        caches.open(appVersion+'-offline').then(function(cache) {
        cache.add(new Request(response.url));
    });
      }
      return(response);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log( 'mtSW: Error fetching. Serving content from cache: ' + error );

      //Check to see if you have it in the cache
      //Return response
      //If not in the cache, then return error page
      return caches.open(appVersion+'-offline').then(function (cache) {
        return cache.match(event.request).then(function (matching) {
          var report =  !matching || matching.status == 404?Promise.reject('no-match'): matching;
          return report
        });
      });
    })
  );
})
```

I checked the `mtShowInstallButton` function. It's fully working on desktop.

What does this mean? On the Desktop, I never got this warning, just when using a handheld device/emulator.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the manifest and service worker code? This would be useful to anyone trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch function is used to fetch JSon manifest file. Try reading google docs again. 
For adding PWA in Mobile you need manifest file to be fetched which is fetched using service-worker using fetch function.

Here is the code :

```
    fetch('examples/example.json')
.then(function(response) {
  // Do stuff with the response
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error);
});
```

for more about fetch and manifest [try this](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-the-fetch-api).

Comment: Good idea but my manifest is loaded base64 encoded via data URI. So it's actually not fetched by my Service Worker.

Comment: why base64 uri? you have to keep manifest file with sw.js in same folder. It means there is no any manifest file present for service worker. Try keeping it physically with servic worker. js. If you didn't get after this also try my article on pwa. https://medium.com/@amitgandole

Comment: The manifest is client-side JS generated as it's dependent on the users device and preferences.

Comment: @JasMich.de Did you ever find a solution for this? I am in the exact same scenario.